# Pass a variable from Visual Studio build event to Wix

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I need to define a variable in the Pre-Build event of my Visual Studio project to be used later by Wix.

Since the build event allows me to execute commands, my idea was to add a new environment variable (I've tried both `set` and `setx`):

```
setx AppIcon MyIcon.ico
```

And then I've tried to read it in my Main.wxs file:

```
<Icon Id="AppIcon" SourceFile="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)..\ApplicationIcon\$(env.AppIcon)" />
```

But of course, I got *Undefined preprocessor variable '$(env.AppIcon)'*.

Any other ideas on how to accomplish this? Is it possible?

Comment: One idea is to change your WiX source to reference a variable from an include file. Then in your prebuild event, call a utility (that you write) that can set the appropriate value in the include file. Here is an example on using an include file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973764/1202501

Comment: Thanks, that should work. Although it's not difficult, I was expecting that there was a simpler way and I was missing it.